# Find a Liapunov function of this linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I'm trying to study the behavior of equilibrium point in the origin of the linear system associated with this matrix:
$$
       A= \begin{pmatrix}
         0 & 1 \\
         0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$, since they aren't negative, we know that this system is not asymptotically stable.

I'm trying to find a Liapunov function to prove this system is stable, but I couldn't find it.

I need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any luck with the answer below?

Comment: @Did No, I really appreciate your try to help me, but I didn't understand what you meant :(

Comment: And you carefully stayed silent about it? Well, this is your call, isn't it?

Comment: @Did I didn't understand what you meant, this is my call?

Comment: To stay silent about it is definitely your call, yes.

Comment: @Did I really didn't understand, what do you mean by "call"?

Comment: @Did Anyway, I didn't stay silent, I tried to solve this question without progress and I will try again in the future, that's why I didn't say anything, because I'm still trying.

Comment: Your definition of "(not) staying silent" is not the usual one, apparently. Once again: this is your choice.

Comment: @Did ok, I'm trying to solve right now this question.

Comment: @Did ha now I understand what you meant by "this is your call", I didn't know this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This system is solved explicitely by $(x(t),y(t))=(x(0)+y(0)t,y(0))$. (Un)stability of the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ follows by inspection.

Comment: I didn't understand, I'm really new on this subject, please give more information.

Comment: I didn't understand why $(x(t),y(t))=(x(0)+y(0)t,y(0))$

Comment: Try to write down what $X'(t)=AX(t)$ means in terms of the coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of the vector $X(t)$.

Comment: yes, I solved explicitly this system and I had the same solution as yours, but I couldn't prove the (un)stability of the system, maybe if I try to draw the phase diagram?